# how to find an average of attributes in Xquery?

Tags: attributes, find, xquery, average

This is given:

```
<tourism>
    <hotel name = "radisson">
        <room id="001" price = "150">
        <room id="002" price = "250">
    </hotel>
</tourism>
```

I am trying to find the average of the prices for every hotel inside tourism. Is this the right code?
The output should be name of hotel and average price of rooms in that hotel.

```
FOR $h in (document("tourism.xml")tourism/hotel[name=$n]
LET $a = avg(document("tourism.xml") $h/@price)
RETURN    <tourism> 
              $n        //returns hotel name
              $a        //returns average prices of all rooms
          </tourism>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but why are you asking if it is the right code? Try running it and see for yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<tourism>
{
  for $hotel in doc("tourism.xml")/tourism/hotel
  return
    <hotel>
      <name>{string($hotel/@name)}</name>
      <average>{avg($hotel/room/xs:float(@price)}</average>
    </hotel>
}
</tourism>
```